# Insert function for singly linked list using two structs C programming

Tags: c

I am not sure if my implementation for inserting a node in a singly linked list is correct. I know how to insert it with a node and data, but for this,  have to use two structs for insertion. So I have two structs, a card struct which has values of suits and cardValue and a node struct, which has the next pointer and the card struct. I want to insert the card data into the node in an ordered list. I also created my own function to compare the values. Here is what I have:

```
typedef struct _Card
{       
        char cardValues[2];
        char suits;
} Card;

typedef struct _Node
{       
        struct Card *card;
        struct Node *next;
} ListNode;

ListNode *insertNode(ListNode *prev, Card *data)
{
        ListNode *current = prev;

        while((current->next != NULL) && (compareStruct(prev, data) < 0))
        {
                prev = prev->next;
        }
}

int compareStruct(ListNode *node, Card *card)
{
        int retVal = 0;

        if(strcmp(node->next->card->cardValues, card->cardValues) < 0)
                retVal = 0;
        else
                retVal = 1;
        return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Hi bubbles.  What is your question?

Comment: Your `insertNode` doesn't actually insert anything, nor does it return anything as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting your structure into your linked list is the same as inserting any other type of data:

1. Pass in a pointer to the head of your list
2. Travel to the desired location in the list
3. Point your previous last node to point to your new elements, and your new element to point to the previous node that was at that location

With this in mind, a few things should change about your insertNode function. First and foremost - you should pass in an already created **Node***, as opposed to the **Card*** you are currently passing in. You're seeking to add another node into your list, not simply a card. Additionally, you usually want to pass in the Head node of your linked list. With this in mind, here is something to help you out!

```
void insertNode(ListNode* node, ListNode* toInsert) {
   while(node->next != null && **Your comparison function here**) {
     node = node->next;
   }
   //Here check if you added at the end, or in the middle
   if(node->next == null) {
     //This is the end of the list - simply add
     node->next = toInsert;
     toInsert->next = null;
   }
   else {
     //If you're here, you added in the middle.
     ListNode* temp = node->next;
     node->next = toInsert;
     toInsert->next = temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: This function doesn't provide any way to add a node to an empty list.

Comment: @aschepler You are absolutely right. Here I am assuming he already had some form of a linked list due to the name of his function, but I am happy to change mine if he desires further help